# finding the IP address which is connect to InterNet IN a PC

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming

Server machine has more than one IP where one IP is connected with local LAN and 
Other is connected with WAN(Internet).

Server Application need to bind the IP and Port so that it can listen to the  Client.
I am able to get the All Ip in ther server machine but facing problem in finding
the the active IP  i.e. IP connected internet.

following code will give all the IP in the system.

```
 char chHostName[MAX_PATH];

  if ( gethostname(chHostName, sizeof(chHostName)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
      return ;
  }    
struct hostent *phe = gethostbyname(chHostName);

  if (phe == 0)
  {    
      return ;

  }
//struct in_addr addrLocalIP;

  for (int i = 0; phe->h_addr_list[i] != 0; ++i) 
  {

    memcpy(&m_addrLocal.sin_addr.S_un, phe->h_addr_list[i], sizeof(struct in_addr));        
  }
```

**1. Is there any way to find the IP which is connected with internet among many IP in the system.**
**2. Is last IP fetched through the above program is always the IP which is connected with Internet?**

Comment: For 1. you would have to parse the routing table and make the assumption that the default gateway is the uplink (it usually is) 2. you can never really tell without a traceroute on a particular interface, I reckon.

Comment: There is no way to know.  Zero or more IPs may be routable to the internet depending on path and routing tables that are outside the program's control.

Answer (score 0):

See [Why no “what's my ip” well-known port/service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1178402/725163) and related answers

Answer (score 0):

Sockets don't know what they are being used for. Your application will have to get the IP address of the internet NIC from a configuration file or similar.